# How to download hugging face sentiment-analysis pipeline to use it offline?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

**How to download hugging face sentiment-analysis pipeline to use it offline?** I'm unable to use hugging face sentiment analysis pipeline without internet. How to download that pipeline?

The basic code for sentiment analysis using hugging face is

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis') #This code will download the pipeline
classifier('We are very happy to show you the  Transformers library.')
```

And the output is

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9997795224189758}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [save_pretrained()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.Pipeline.save_pretrained) method to save the configs, model weights and vocabulary:

```py
classifier.save_pretrained('/some/directory')
```

and load it by specifying the tokenizer and model parameter:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

c2 = pipeline(task = 'sentiment-analysis', model='/some/directory', tokenizer='/some/directory')
```

Comment: Also found that using directly `pipeline(task='sentiment-analysis', model='/some/directory', tokenizer='/some/directory')` works. Though it is unclear that this is possible by reading the doc.

Comment: Okay, If we consider the single pipeline code just from transformers import pipeline is enough right?

Comment: It's saying cannot import 'AutoModelForSequenceClassification' from 'transformers'. I don't know why

Comment: The code is not working, it's throwing an error like 
OSError: Can't load config for '\Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline'. Make sure that:

- '\Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or '\Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file

Comment: The code is working fine. You are probably want to use `Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline` (in case you have your python interpreter running in the same directory as `Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline`) without a backslash or even better the absolute path. @NithinReddy

Comment: yea, it's working fine. We have to load the model with AutoModelForSequenceClassification and AutoTokenizer.

Comment: You do not have to do that as shown above. The problem was your strange path string with a leading backslash @NithinReddy

Comment: Yea, backslash is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to handle this:

```
import os
from transformers import pipeline

if os.path.isdir('hf_cache/'):
    pipe = pipeline(task='sentiment-analysis',
                          model_kwargs={"cache_dir": 'hf_cache/', 'local_files_only': True})
else:
    pipe = pipeline(task='sentiment-analysis',
                          model_kwargs={"cache_dir": 'hf_cache/', 'force_download': True})
```

Take a look into [from_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model) parameters.